# Porting Underscore's some function to swift

Tags: ios, swift, functional-programming

As a learning exercise, I'm porting some of Underscore.js's utility functions over to swift and I'm starting with `some` which returns true if any elements in a collection pass a given collection block.

The naive implementation:

```
extension Sequence {
    func some(_ predicate: (Self.Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        return reduce(false) { $0 || predicate($1) }
    }
}
```

I noticed however that a lot of the STL functions include `throws` and `rethrows`. A great example is the `filter` function which has a function signature of:

```
func filter(_ isIncluded: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> [Element]
```

Could someone show me how to write the `some` function while also utilizing the `throw` and `rethrows` capabilities?

Answer (score 0):

This blog post is a good overview: http://robnapier.net/re-throws

Basically, `rethrows` is an indicator that a function will only throw if one of its closure parameters throws. This makes enforces that you don't have to handle throwing if you call the function with a closure that doesn't throw. In your case, you would just define your extension method as:

```
extension Sequence {
    func some(_ predicate: (Self.Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool {
        return reduce(false) { $0 || try predicate($1) }
    }
}
```

Now, `some` will accept a throwing or non-throwing predicate, and if you give it a non-throwing predicate, you don't need to worry about `try`.

Comment: I did try that already but it fails to compile saying "call can throw but is not marked with try" which makes sense. I actually did figure out how to accomplish it by using `map` and `reduce` in combination, I'll post an answer to share.

Comment: Whoops. I forgot to put a `try` in front of the predicate invocation. I'll update the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to end up solving my question by using a combination of `map` and `reduce`. I made a quick playground:

```
extension Sequence {
    func some(_ predicate: (Self.Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool {
        return try map(predicate).reduce(false) { $0 || $1 }
    }
}

let list = [1, 2, 3]
list.some({ $0 == 1 }) // true
list.some({ $0 % 50 == 0 }) // false
```

Using map, you apply the predicate to each element, mapping the entire array into an array of bools, then OR'ing them together.

It's not the most efficient algorithm and there are some clear optimizations that can be made such as returning as soon as you encounter a `true` value, etc but I do like the simple functional nature of the solution.